# WSO2 APIM Management: Use standard ports for HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, wso2-api-manager

I am currently working on deploying the WSO2 APIM on a Kubernetes cluster. All the pods and services are configured and running correctly. 
On the ingress settings we want to use expose default HTTP ports 80/443 instead of the default ports used by the product i.e. 9763/9443. We are not using any offsets for the port.

When testing the config we notice that the URL is always being redirected to port 9443 which is being blocked by the ingress.

Enabling HTTP protocol for admin also does not work as the redirection is happening to the default HTTP port configured in the product i.e. 9763

Is there a configuration in the carbon.xml/axis2.xml which can be changed to achieve the desired result or do we need to make changes in the Ingress setting for rewriting the URLs.

Comment: Have you looked here for example: https://dzone.com/articles/running-wso2-identity-server-on-port-443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set proxy ports in PRODUCT_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml file. For 9443 you can set the port 443 and for port 9763 you can use the port 80.

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="9763"
                proxyPort="80" ............


<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="9443"
            proxyPort="443" ...........
```

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon430/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path

Comment: I tried this. While the default port issue is resolved, i get a 404 error on the following url: /publisher/site/pages/login.jag?requestedPage=/publisher/                                                                     When I configured reverse proxy for publisher as per [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer), i get TOO MANY REDIRECTS issue

Comment: Just change the ports in catalina-server. Other changes are nor required for your use case